# Cannot find how to duplicate a photo or a video in iOS 16

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

In previous iOS versions, you could select a photo or a video from your Photos app and duplicate it (so you can edit it and try filters on it without risking to delete the original file, for example):

[image]

However, I cannot find this option in iOS 16:

[image]

### **Where did the option to duplicate a video or photo go?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple moved it to the photo app (top right circle with three dots … next to Edit)

[image]

It’s gone from the share sheet, so I would recommend the Exify app by Iconfactory which has a duplicate action right where you want it.

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/exify-tools-for-photos/id974769286

[image: screen capture from iOS share sheet / action sheet]

Comment: Thank you so much! Another update, another round of features that become hard to find and years of muscle memory to unlearn! But at least some people can justify their paychecks by not staying completely idle all day, I guess. 

Comment: I figure I need three full time weeks to catch up on iOS 15 and 16. One extra week for iPadOS. macOS, going to be months to do a deep dive.